# Access control to method in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing this for educational purposes, so imagine that i have an objects called A, B and C, if B calls a method on A, A will do it, if C calls a method on A, A won't do it.

An analouges, Imaging A is you, B is your dad and C is someone else, if your dad tells you something, you have to do it without asking, if someone else tells you something, you aren't obliged to do it.

I didn't find an answer for this behavior, please someone can describe how to do it, and shows me an example in Java.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Post some code you've written to try to solve this and I will gladly help

Comment: This sounds like a metaphor for a protected method

Comment: @JeremyHanlon it's not homework, just sometimes when i have free time i think, really i think for a solution, but i didn't find any answer.

Comment: @Natecat mmmmmmm, but if i don't want to inherit the class??

Answer (score 0):

This code would be one way to do it if you included a list of bosses in the constructor:

```
public class Me {
    private ArrayList<Object> bosses=new ArrayList<Object>();

    public Me(ArrayList<Object> myBosses) {
        this.bosses=myBosses;
    }
    public void AnOrderToDo(Object orderer,int randomArg){
        for(Object o:bosses){
            if(o==orderer){
                //TODO method code here
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Use o.equals(orderer) instead of ==

Comment: @JeremyHanlon, we just should do `if(bosses.contains(orderer)){method code here...}`.

Comment: @C L K Kissane it seems logical your solution, thank you.

Comment: o.equals(orderer) wont always work if the object has an equals method that could return true for not the exact same object. Also contains uses .equals too so that wont work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a package containing only classes A and B and use the default  access modifier for the methods that should not be called from other classes.

The default access modifier allows only the class itself and classes in the other packages to see the methods, so if C is in another package will not even be able to see the method.

Example:

Class A in package stackoverflow.defaultModifier

```
package stackoverflow.defaultModifier;
public class A {
//NOTICE THE ABSENCE OF PUBLIC/PRIVATE/PROTECTED, is using the default access modifier
    void printHello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Class B in package stackoverflow.defaultModifier can access to printHello()

```
package stackoverflow.defaultModifier;
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.printHello();
    }
}
```

Class C in package **stackoverflow.externalClasses** cannot access printHello() (Error: printHello() is not public in class A, cannot be accessed from outside package)

```
package stackoverflow.externalClasses;
import stackoverflow.defaultModifier.A;
public class C {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.printHell(); //compilation error!
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: thank you for your time, i already knows package-private, but i didn't think it.